# Azure Cosmos DB Test Multi-region Write Conflict in Emulator

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there any way that we can test multi-region write conflict in a unit test by using the emulator? Does SDK provide some methods so we can insert a conflict and then read it back?

Comment: What do you mean by conflict: what conflicting with what?

Comment: @Richard Just updated. It's for multi-region write conflict.

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#differences-between-the-emulator-and-the-service:

> The Azure Cosmos Emulator does not offer multi-region replication.

So it seems the answer would be "No".

Comment: Yep that's what i thought :). Maybe someone from cosmos db team can confirm.